# is this correct way in vue or not

Tags: vue.js

hello guys i found that i can return data but few things create confusion can anybody tell is this method is correct or not

**method 1:**

```
  <script>
      export default {
         data () {
            return {
                     nav: [],
                   }
            },
   mounted () {
             this.checkSidebarVisibility()
           },
   methods: {
           checkSidebarVisibility: function() {
            this.nav= navnew
      } 
  },
</script>
```

i know this method is 100% correct but when i use this method i faced problem like data is loading too late for eg :- if i use this method for select drop down then dat in select option after few second (atleast 3 sec)

**method 2:**

i have little confusion is this method is correct way in vue for eg:

```
  <script>
     export default {
          data () {
            return {
                     nav: this.checkSidebarVisibility(),
                   }
            },

   methods: {
           checkSidebarVisibility: function() {
            this.nav= navnew
      } 
   },
 </script>
```

i found this method load data quicky in select option as well as work fluent i.e without any error in browser console but i confused   that is this correct way of vue can any expert can give any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **set some property of `data`** as soon as possible, use `created()` instead of `mounted()`. That is because `created()` is **the earliest [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram)** where the `data` has been initialized.

```html
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        nav: [],
      }
    },
    created() {                        // using created() instead of mounted()
      this.checkSidebarVisibility()
    },
    methods: {
      checkSidebarVisibility: function() {
        this.nav = navnew
      }
    },
    // ...
  }
</script>
```

If, on the other hand, your code that fills the data is **asynchronous**, e.g. an ajax call, you could dispatch the request from an even earlier hook, the `beforeCreate()`:

```html
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        nav: [],
      }
    },
    beforeCreate() {                  // using beforeCreate() instead of created()
      this.checkSidebarVisibility()   // assuming it is async, e.g. ajax
    },
    methods: {
      checkSidebarVisibility: function() {
        this.nav = navnew
      }
    },
    // ...
  }
</script>
```

This is possible because the initialization of Vue is synchronous, meaning even if your async operation (ajax) dispatched at `beforeCreate()` returns instantly, the `data` will already have been initialized (something that happens between the `beforeCreate` and `created` hooks).